# Someone's peeled all the stickers off of my The Witness puzzle! Can you still solve it?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

*Note: You will need to know the rules of the puzzle symbols in The Witness. This post probably still contains spoilers for The Witness, though, so the puzzle has been placed into a spoiler.*

---

Someone's peeled all the stickers off of my The Witness puzzle! Can you still solve it?

> [image]

Comment: Could you help to provide the rules of the puzzle symbols in The Witness?

Comment: Part of The Witness is figuring out what the symbols mean, so these links explaining them are SPOILERS for the game. [1](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Puzzle_Types#Tetris_Blocks) [2](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witness/Puzzle_Types#Upside-Down_Y_.2F_Elimination_Marks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick to this puzzle is that

> the stickers can be rotated! Even though they're not tilted to signify this, when we're placing them on the board we can put them back in a different orientation. (Notice how the Y symbol has also been rotated.)

Once we realize that, the solution comes fairly quickly.

> [image]
>  The pieces can be moved around, but this is the only line that works. (I've placed the pieces here to give an indication of how they apply.)

Comment: Yep, pretty much. It wasn't too easy to get a unique line with these constraints. (The Y symbol was a last-minute edit since I didn't think it would be too fair to have the Y symbol the right way up.)